# Geth sync too slow on MacMini to catch up with latest blocks

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, mac-osx

My workaround used to be do a `geth -removedb` and start a fresh fast sync from scratch. Trying to sync with existing blockchain data instead was a lost race of catching up to the latest block.

Today even the workaround in fast sync mode (cache -1024) will not completely load the blockchain anymore. It catches up some 100-300 blocks to the latest block and stalls for hours. By the time it catches up a few hundred blocks, the latest block moved ahead again. For 4 days now. Frustrating. Any ideas?

> MacMini 4GB RAM (latest MacMini doesn't support field RAM upgrade)
>   VDSL connection with an average of 20-40Mbit throughput
>   Geth 1.6.1 / go1.8.1 /Ethereum Wallet 0.9.0

Comment: Remove the entire `chaindata` folder and try.

Comment: (Just commenting on this old question.) If your MacMini is running with an HDD rather than SSD, it's unlikely it'll ever catch up to the latest block...

Answer (score 0):

If you only have a few hundred remaining just check your system time. Enable network time synchronisation if you can, then restart geth. This may solve your problem.

You can try this:

```
sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```